# django core.mail.send_mail works fine but EmailMessage.send fails

Tags: python, django, email

Trying to send email with a 'reply-to' option as below.

```
    msg = EmailMessage(
            subject='title/subject',
            body='<h1>h1 text</h1><h2>h2 text</h2>',
            from_email='FROM-ADDR',
            to=['TO-ADDRESS',],
            reply_to=['RE-TO-ADDR',],
        )
    msg.content_subtype='html'
    msg.send()
```

It gives SMTPDataError at /send_mail 
(550, b'Request failed; Mailbox unavailable')

However, if I just use django.core.mail.send_mail, it works fine as below.

```
to = ['TO-ADDRESS',]
from_email = 'FROM-ADDR'
subject= 'subject'
text = 'SOME TEXT'
html_message = '<h1>abc</h1>'
mail.send_mail(subject, text, from_email, to, html_message=html_message)
```

Comment: Forgot to state that the version is django 2.2.6

Comment: Have you tried using a valid email address?